# Select soft keyboard in Android 7.0

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, soft-keyboard

My custom keyboard is not visible on the soft keyboard list. How can it be listed in the input method dialog?
It is working fine in other OS, but in Android Nougat it is not displaying.

I am using the source code below.

```
    private void showInputMethodPicker() {
        InputMethodManager imeManager = (InputMethodManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        if (imeManager != null) {
            imeManager.showInputMethodPicker();
        } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error in keyboard", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
boolean isListedInKeyboardMethod() {

        boolean flag = false;
        InputMethodManager imeManager = (InputMethodManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        List<InputMethodInfo> InputMethods = imeManager.getEnabledInputMethodList();
        for (InputMethodInfo info : InputMethods) {
            if(info.getId().equalsIgnoreCase(keyboard_name))
                return true;
        }

        return flag;

    }



private void showInputMethodPicker() {
    InputMethodManager imeManager = (InputMethodManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    if (imeManager != null) {
        imeManager.showInputMethodPicker();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error in keyboard", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```